# Display KML file in the map

Tags: javascript, openlayers, kml

I have code that performs geocoding and show layers. Now I want to add the KML file display feature.There are the code in the openlayers library for this.I combined the code but it does not answer. please guide me.It looks like the problem is in the following code:

interactions:ol.interaction.defaultInteractions().extend([dragAndDropInteraction])
interactions:ol.interaction.defaults({ altShiftDragRotate:false, pinchRotate:false })

this is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bing Maps</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v5.3.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
    <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
    <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/build/ol.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <meta name="description" content="Control to add a grid reference to a map." />
    <meta name="keywords" content="ol3, control, search, BAN, french, places, autocomplete" />

    <!-- FontAwesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE 9 bug on ajax tranport  -->
    <!--[if lte IE 9]>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ajaxtransport-xdomainrequest/1.0.3/jquery.xdomainrequest.min.js'></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- Openlayers -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/latest/css/ol.css" />

    <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL,Object.assign"></script>

    <!-- ol-ext -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/dist/ol-ext.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/dist/ol-ext.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css"/>
    <style>
        .ol-search ul {
            color: #333;
            font-size:0.85em;
            max-width: 21em;
        }
        .ol-search ul i {
            display: block;
            color: #333;
            font-size:0.85em;
        }
        .info {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .info a img {
            height: 100px;
            margin-right: .5em;
            float: left;
        }
    </style>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
      } 
      .map {
        height: 90%;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <style>
      .tooltip {
        position: relative;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        border-radius: 4px;
        color: white;
        padding: 4px 8px;
        opacity: 0.7;
        white-space: nowrap;
      }
      .tooltip-measure {
        opacity: 1;
        font-weight: bold;
      }
      .tooltip-static {
        background-color: #ffcc33;
        color: black;
        border: 1px solid white;
      }
      .tooltip-measure:before,
      .tooltip-static:before {
        border-top: 6px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        border-right: 6px solid transparent;
        border-left: 6px solid transparent;
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        bottom: -6px;
        margin-left: -7px;
        left: 50%;
      }
      .tooltip-static:before {
        border-top-color: #ffcc33;
      }  
      .map {
        height: 50%;
        width: 70%;
      }   

      </style>
  </head>
  <body>
     <div id="map" class="map"></div>
     <div id="info">&nbsp;</div>

     <div>
      <label>Map or Arial picture: &nbsp;</label>
     <select id="layer-select">
       <option value="AerialWithLabels" selected>Arial picture</option>

       <option value="osmmap">Map </option>
     </select>
     </div>
    <script>


       var source = new ol.source.Vector();

      var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: source,
        style: new ol.style.Style({
          fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
          }),
          stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#ffcc33',
            width: 2
          }),
          image: new ol.style.Circle({
            radius: 7,
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
              color: '#ffcc33'
            })
          })
        })
      });


      /**
       * Currently drawn feature.
       * @type {ol.Feature}
       */
      var sketch;


      /**
       * The help tooltip element.
       * @type {Element}
       */
      var helpTooltipElement;


      /**
       * Overlay to show the help messages.
       * @type {ol.Overlay}
       */
      var helpTooltip;


      /**
       * The measure tooltip element.
       * @type {Element}
       */
      var measureTooltipElement;


      /**
       * Overlay to show the measurement.
       * @type {ol.Overlay}
       */
      var measureTooltip;


      /**
       * Message to show when the user is drawing a polygon.
       * @type {string}
       */
      var continuePolygonMsg = 'Click to continue drawing the polygon';


      /**
       * Message to show when the user is drawing a line.
       * @type {string}
       */
      var continueLineMsg = 'Click to continue drawing the line';


      /**
       * Handle pointer move.
       * @param {ol.MapBrowserEvent} evt The event.
       */
      var pointerMoveHandler = function(evt) {
        if (evt.dragging) {
          return;
        }
        /** @type {string} */
        var helpMsg = 'برای اندازه گیری کلیک کنید';

        if (sketch) {
          var geom = (sketch.getGeometry());
          if (geom instanceof ol.geom.Polygon) {
            helpMsg = continuePolygonMsg;
          } else if (geom instanceof ol.geom.LineString) {
            helpMsg = continueLineMsg;
          }
        }

        helpTooltipElement.innerHTML = helpMsg;
        helpTooltip.setPosition(evt.coordinate);

        helpTooltipElement.classList.remove('hidden');
      };


      var styles = [
        'AerialWithLabels',
        'osmmap'
      ];
      var layers = [];
      var i, ii;
      for (i = 0, ii = styles.length; i < ii-1; ++i) {
        layers.push(new ol.layer.Tile({
          visible: false,
          preload: Infinity,
          source: new ol.source.BingMaps({
            key: 'Ar3HbeAWJ2BNWw49Jnce_gbrbyqiPSBFuci9N4942gLNyBZgfzFPYn0d4QvpH06G ',
            imagerySet: styles[i]
            // use maxZoom 19 to see stretched tiles instead of the BingMaps
            // "no photos at this zoom level" tiles
            // maxZoom: 19
          })
        }));
      }
      layers.push(new ol.layer.Tile({
          visible: false,
          preload: Infinity,
          source: new ol.source.OSM({
            imagerySet: styles[1]
            // use maxZoom 19 to see stretched tiles instead of the BingMaps
            // "no photos at this zoom level" tiles
            // maxZoom: 19
          })
        }));
        layers.push(vector);
        // kml
    var dragAndDropInteraction = new ol.interaction.DragAndDrop({
        formatConstructors: [
          ol.format.GPX,
          ol.format.GeoJSON,
          ol.format.IGC,
          ol.format.KML,
          ol.format.TopoJSON
        ]
      });
      //end kml
      var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: layers,
        // Improve user experience by loading tiles while dragging/zooming. Will make
        // zooming choppy on mobile or slow devices.
        loadTilesWhileInteracting: true,
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
          center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([51.39, 35.70]),
          zoom: 10
        }),
        interactions:ol.interaction.defaultInteractions().extend([dragAndDropInteraction])
      });

      var select = document.getElementById('layer-select');
      function onChange() {
        var style = select.value;
        for (var i = 0, ii = layers.length; i < ii; ++i) {
          layers[i].setVisible(styles[i] === style);
        }
      }
      select.addEventListener('change', onChange);
      onChange();

           map.on('pointermove', pointerMoveHandler);

      map.getViewport().addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
        helpTooltipElement.classList.add('hidden');
      });

      // Current selection
    var sLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector(),
        style: new ol.style.Style({
            image: new ol.style.Circle({
                radius: 5,
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke ({
                    color: 'rgb(255,165,0)',
                    width: 3
                }),
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                    color: 'rgba(255,165,0,.3)'
                })
            }),
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke ({
                color: 'rgb(255,165,0)',
                width: 3
            }),
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: 'rgba(255,165,0,.3)'
            })
        })
    });
    map.addLayer(sLayer);

    // Set the search control 
    var search = new ol.control.SearchNominatim (
        {   //target: $(".options").get(0),
            polygon: $("#polygon").prop("checked"),
            position: true  // Search, with priority to geo position
        });
    map.addControl (search);

    // Select feature when click on the reference index
    search.on('select', function(e)
        {   // console.log(e);
            sLayer.getSource().clear();
            // Check if we get a geojson to describe the search
            if (e.search.geojson) {
                var format = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
                var f = format.readFeature(e.search.geojson, { dataProjection: "EPSG:4326", featureProjection: map.getView().getProjection() });
                sLayer.getSource().addFeature(f);
                var view = map.getView();
                var resolution = view.getResolutionForExtent(f.getGeometry().getExtent(), map.getSize());
                var zoom = view.getZoomForResolution(resolution);
                var center = ol.extent.getCenter(f.getGeometry().getExtent());
                // redraw before zoom
                setTimeout(function(){
                        view.animate({
                        center: center,
                        zoom: Math.min (zoom, 16)
                    });
                }, 100);
            }
            else {
                map.getView().animate({
                    center:e.coordinate,
                    zoom: Math.max (map.getView().getZoom(),16)
                });
            }
        });
        //kml

      dragAndDropInteraction.on('addfeatures', function(event) {
        var vectorSource = new ol.source.VectorSource({
          features: event.features
        });
        map.addLayer(new ol.layer.VectorLayer({
          source: vectorSource
        }));
        map.getView().fit(vectorSource.getExtent());
      });
      //
      var displayFeatureInfo = function(pixel) {
        var features = [];
        map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature) {
          features.push(feature);
        });
        if (features.length > 0) {
          var info = [];
          var i, ii;
          for (i = 0, ii = features.length; i < ii; ++i) {
            info.push(features[i].get('name'));
          }
          document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = info.join(', ') || '&nbsp';
        } else {
          document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
        }
      };
      //
      map.on('pointermove', function(evt) {
        if (evt.dragging) {
          return;
        }
        var pixel = map.getEventPixel(evt.originalEvent);
        displayFeatureInfo(pixel);
      });

      map.on('click', function(evt) {
        displayFeatureInfo(evt.pixel);
      });

      //end kml


    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is the code:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some errors in your code where you have changed from modules to full build syntax

```
interactions:ol.interaction.defaultInteractions().extend([dragAndDropInteraction])

var vectorSource = new ol.source.VectorSource({

map.addLayer(new ol.layer.VectorLayer({
```

Should be

```
interactions:ol.interaction.defaults().extend([dragAndDropInteraction])

var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({

map.addLayer(new ol.layer.Vector({
```

Comment: Thanks. It is useful.

Comment: I have other question. How to show files without drag-drop and with upload files from memory?